# Tikzpicture in a two column way using a one column .cls template

Tags: pgfplots, floats, two-column, ieeetran

I'm using a `.cls` IEEEtran from IEEE available here http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html; and all document is in two columns.

I'm ploting using `pgfplots` a graphic but it is using just one column and i want that it occupies all the two columns.

An example code of the plot is:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcounter{groupcount}
\pgfplotsset{
    draw group line/.style n args={5}{
        after end axis/.append code={
            \setcounter{groupcount}{0}
            \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{#1}\of\datatable\as\cell{%
                \def\temp{#2}
                \ifx\temp\cell
                    \ifnum\thegroupcount=0
                        \stepcounter{groupcount}
                        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{[index]0}\of\datatable
                        \coordinate [yshift=#4] (startgroup) at (axis cs:\pgfplotsretval,0);
                    \else
                        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{[index]0}\of\datatable
                        \coordinate [yshift=#4] (endgroup) at (axis cs:\pgfplotsretval,0);
                    \fi
                \else
                    \ifnum\thegroupcount=1
                        \setcounter{groupcount}{0}
                        \draw [
                            shorten >=-#5,
                            shorten <=-#5
                        ] (startgroup) -- node [anchor=north] {#3} (endgroup);
                    \fi
                \fi
            }
            \ifnum\thegroupcount=1
                        \setcounter{groupcount}{0}
                        \draw [
                            shorten >=-#5,
                            shorten <=-#5
                        ] (startgroup) -- node [anchor=north] {#3} (endgroup);
            \fi
        }
    }
}
\pgfplotstableread{
%Res. Number    Res A.  Res.B   Group
1               0.5     4.224   1
2               0.6     4.124   1
3               0.7     4.067   1
4               0.8     4.88    1
5               0.9     4.391   1
6               1       4.273   1
7               1.1     5.506   2
8               1.2     5.391   2
9               1.3     5.52    2
10              1.4     5.418   2
11              1.5     5.285   2
12              1.6     5.194   2
13              0.5     6.224   3
14              0.6     6.124   3
15              .7      6.067   3
16              0.8     6.88    3
17              0.9     6.391   3
18              1       6.273   3
19              1.1     8.506   4
20              1.2     8.391   4
21              1.3     8.52    4
22              1.4     8.418   4
23              1.5     8.285   4
24              1.6     8.194   4
}\sindezoito

\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[b!]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked, compat=newest, %Better label placement
enlarge y limits=false,
ymin=0,
enlarge x limits = .1,
bar width=12pt,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},anchor=north,legend columns=0},
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
ylabel={Power $(mW)$},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords=\rotatebox{90}{\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
axis lines*=left,
y axis line style={opacity=0},
yticklabels={\empty},
ytick style={draw=none},
cycle list={
    {fill=black!60,draw=black!60},
    {fill=black!40,draw=black!40},
    {fill=black!20,draw=black!20}
},
axis on top,
major grid style=white,
ymajorgrids,
xticklabels =   {BS,BS-A,HP,HP-A,LP,LP-A,BP,BP-A,HP,HP-A,LP,LP-A,
                 BS,BS-A,HP,HP-A,LP,LP-A,BP,BP-A,HP,HP-A,LP,LP-A},
legend style={
      font=\footnotesize,
      cells={anchor=west},
      legend columns=5,
      at={(0.5,-0.2)},
      anchor=north,
      /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.2cm}
    },    
%           draw group line={[index]3}{1}{30c - 180}{-3.5ex}{7pt},
%        draw group line={[index]3}{2}{50c - 180}{-3.5ex}{7pt},
%        draw group line={[index]3}{1}{30c - 350}{-3.5ex}{7pt},
%        draw group line={[index]3}{2}{50c - 350}{-3.5ex}{7pt},           
    ]


\addplot table[x index=0,y index=1] \sindezoito;
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=2] \sindezoito;
\legend{Switching, Internal Cell}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Power results examples forum.}
\label{fig:0.18.sin}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I tried to use:

```
\begin{figure*}
\end{figure*}
```

But it didn't work.
Anyone may help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `[b!]` specifier and you don't have any text so weird things are bound to happen. Also please truncate the example next time to isolate the issue, you don't use many of the packages here.

You need to use the starred version of the figure environment otherwise it forces the figure to be on one of columns for which location specifiers make sense. Otherwise I recommend leaving it alone. You can read an excellent summary in [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/3235) to get more info about the starred version.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum} %<-- For dummy text
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}


\newcounter{groupcount}
\pgfplotsset{
    draw group line/.style n args={5}{
        after end axis/.append code={
            \setcounter{groupcount}{0}
            \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{#1}\of\datatable\as\cell{%
                \def\temp{#2}
                \ifx\temp\cell
                    \ifnum\thegroupcount=0
                        \stepcounter{groupcount}
                        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{[index]0}\of\datatable
                        \coordinate [yshift=#4] (startgroup) at (axis cs:\pgfplotsretval,0);
                    \else
                        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{[index]0}\of\datatable
                        \coordinate [yshift=#4] (endgroup) at (axis cs:\pgfplotsretval,0);
                    \fi
                \else
                    \ifnum\thegroupcount=1
                        \setcounter{groupcount}{0}
                        \draw [
                            shorten >=-#5,
                            shorten <=-#5
                        ] (startgroup) -- node [anchor=north] {#3} (endgroup);
                    \fi
                \fi
            }
            \ifnum\thegroupcount=1
                        \setcounter{groupcount}{0}
                        \draw [
                            shorten >=-#5,
                            shorten <=-#5
                        ] (startgroup) -- node [anchor=north] {#3} (endgroup);
            \fi
        }
    }
}
\pgfplotstableread{
%Res. Number    Res A.  Res.B   Group
1               0.5     4.224   1
2               0.6     4.124   1
3               0.7     4.067   1
4               0.8     4.88    1
5               0.9     4.391   1
6               1       4.273   1
7               1.1     5.506   2
8               1.2     5.391   2
9               1.3     5.52    2
10              1.4     5.418   2
11              1.5     5.285   2
12              1.6     5.194   2
13              0.5     6.224   3
14              0.6     6.124   3
15              .7      6.067   3
16              0.8     6.88    3
17              0.9     6.391   3
18              1       6.273   3
19              1.1     8.506   4
20              1.2     8.391   4
21              1.3     8.52    4
22              1.4     8.418   4
23              1.5     8.285   4
24              1.6     8.194   4
}\sindezoito

\title{Some article title}

\author{The Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}
\lipsum[1-6]


\begin{figure*}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked, compat=newest, %Better label placement
enlarge y limits=false,
ymin=0,
enlarge x limits = .1,
bar width=12pt,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},anchor=north,legend columns=0},
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
ylabel={Power $(mW)$},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords=\rotatebox{90}{\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
axis lines*=left,
y axis line style={opacity=0},
yticklabels={\empty},
ytick style={draw=none},
cycle list={
    {fill=black!60,draw=black!60},
    {fill=black!40,draw=black!40},
    {fill=black!20,draw=black!20}
},
axis on top,
major grid style=white,
ymajorgrids,
xticklabels =   {BS,BS-A,HP,HP-A,LP,LP-A,BP,BP-A,HP,HP-A,LP,LP-A,
                 BS,BS-A,HP,HP-A,LP,LP-A,BP,BP-A,HP,HP-A,LP,LP-A},
legend style={
      font=\footnotesize,
      cells={anchor=west},
      legend columns=5,
      at={(0.5,-0.2)},
      anchor=north,
      /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.2cm}
    },    
%           draw group line={[index]3}{1}{30c - 180}{-3.5ex}{7pt},
%        draw group line={[index]3}{2}{50c - 180}{-3.5ex}{7pt},
%        draw group line={[index]3}{1}{30c - 350}{-3.5ex}{7pt},
%        draw group line={[index]3}{2}{50c - 350}{-3.5ex}{7pt},           
    ]


\addplot table[x index=0,y index=1] \sindezoito;
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=2] \sindezoito;
\legend{Switching, Internal Cell}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Power results examples forum.}
\label{fig:0.18.sin}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]